# Different method of evaluating ${d\over dx}(e^x)=e^x$

Tags: derivatives

$$y=e^x\tag1$$
$${dy\over dx}=e^x\tag2$$

We can use the series of $e^x$ to show that ${d\over dx}(e^x)=e^x$ $$e^x=1+x+{x^2\over 2!}+{x^3\over 3!}+\cdots\tag3$$

$${d\over dx}(1+x+{x^2\over 2!}+{x^3\over 3!}+\cdots)=0+1+{2x\over 2!}+{3x^2\over 3!}+\cdots=1+x+{x^2\over 2!}+\cdots=e^x\tag4$$

How else can you show that $${d\over dx}(e^x)=e^x$$ with another method?

Comment: 2 different methods do not suffice? ;)

Comment: So many ways. You can use the logarithm and Then use theorems about derivatives of functional inverses.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $e^x$? If you mean the function whose series is given as you have, then that is the way to show it. If you mean the function whose derivative is itself and at $x=0$ evaluates to 1, then you have it right away. If you have another definition for $e^x$, please let us know so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways. I'll go with a more 'graphical' approach instead of a numerical. We know by the limit definition of the derivative that $m = \frac{\delta y}{\delta x}$, so we can choose any point  $e^x$, $x \in \Bbb{R}$, and find the slope of the tangent line. For instance,

Let's choose a point $x = 1$:

When $x = 1$ $\rightarrow$ $y = e^1$. 
Similarly, when $x = 0$ $\rightarrow y = e^0 = 1$

This yields points $(1,e)$ and $(0,1)$
is 
If $y=mx+b$, then \begin{equation}y =\frac{1-0}{e-1} x +1\end{equation} 
($b \textbf{ is always } 1$ for functions in the form   $f(x) = a^x$ )

\begin{equation}
y = mx+b \\
y =\frac{1-0}{e-1} x +1 \rightarrow y =\frac{x}{e-1} +1\\
y(e-1) = x + 1 \\
x = y(e-1) -1 \\
x = ey -y -1 
\end{equation}

If we take the derivative with respect to $x$ of the equation above, 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = e\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{dy}{dx}  \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}(e - 1)
\end{equation}
Since we know \begin{equation}\frac{dy}{dx} = m\end{equation},  it's implied that \begin{equation}f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx}\end{equation}, which satisfies the assumption that our slope

\begin{equation}m = \frac{\delta y}{\delta x}\end{equation}

You can further manipulate the equations above to prove that the slope of the line passing through both points is equal to $e^x$, no matter what two points you choose.

\begin{equation*}
f(x) =  e^x \\
f(1) = e^1 = e
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
f'(1) =  e^1 \\
f'(1) = e^1 = e
\end{equation*}

Of course, you must provide a graph showing both coordinates. It is an intuitive demonstration of 
\begin{equation} 
lim _{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h)} \\ 
lim _{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{x+h}-e^{x}}{h} \\
=\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}=e^x \\
=\frac{e^x e^h-e^x}{h}=e^x \\
=\frac{e^x(1)-e^x}{h}=e^x.\\
\lim_{h\to0}e^x=e^x 
\end{equation}

or $f'(x) = e^x$ for $f(x) = e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use some implicit differentiation. We have

$$y=e^x,$$ or equivalently $$x=\ln(y),$$ differentiating through with respect to $x$ and then some rearranging gives $$1=\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}\Rightarrow y=\frac{dy}{dx}\Rightarrow e^x=\frac{dy}{dx},$$ as required.

Comment: But assuming $(\log x)'=\frac1x$ is not equivalent to assume $(e^x)'=e^x$ by the differentiation rule for the inverse?

Answer (score 1):

A simple method to see that such "$e$" exists is to consider

- $2^x$ for which we can see that the slope for the secant between $0$ and $1$ is $1$ and thus, by convexity, the slope of the tangent in $0$ is less than $1$
- $4^x$ for which we can see that the slope for the secant between $-\frac12$ and $0$ is also $1$ and thus, by convexity, the slope of the tangent in $0$ is greater than $1$

thus by continuity of the exponential we can conclude that exists $e\in \mathbb{R}$ with $2<e<4$ such that at $x=0$ $(e^x)'=1$, that is

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$

which implies that the derivative of $e^x$ at $x_0$

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{e^{x}-e^{x_0}}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}e^{x_0}\frac{e^{x-x_0}-1}{x-x_0}=e^{x_0}$$

Answer (score 0):

you can also prove it by differentiating via first derivative principle

$\forall x\in R$

$f'(x)=lim_{h\to 0}\ \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

$f'(x)=lim_{h\to 0 \ }\dfrac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}$

$f'(x)=e^{x}\ lim_{h\to 0}\ \dfrac{e^{h}-1}{h}=e^x.\ ln\ e=e^x$

Answer (score 0):

We know that
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1.
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}=e^x.
$$